# Essentially bounded and continuously differentiable a.e. is in some Sobolev space?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be bounded, open and contains the origin. Assume $f\in L^{\infty}(\Omega) \cap C^{1}(\Omega\setminus\{0\})$.\\
1- Must $f$ be weakly differentiable ?
2- If yes, What Sobolev spaces would it be in ?

The function $g(x)=\frac{x_{i}}{|x|}$ enjoys the assumptions and belongs to
$W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ for all $1\leq p <n $ since one can easily estimate
$|\nabla g(x)|\leq \frac{c}{|x|}$.

Answer (score 2):

If $n=1$, then $f(x) = x/|x|$ satisfies the assumptions but it is not weakly differentiable.

In general, if you consider $f(x) = \sin |x|^{-\alpha}$ with $\alpha> n-1$, then $f$ satisfies the assumptions but $|\nabla f|\not\in L^1(B)$ (hence $f\not\in L^p(B)$ for every $p$).

Namely, passing in polar coordinates we have to prove that the integral
$$
\int_0^1 \rho^{n-2-\alpha} |\cos \rho^{-\alpha}|\, d\rho
$$
diverges at $+\infty$.
With the change of variables $z = \rho^{-\alpha}$, up to a multiplicative constant we get the integral
$$
\int_1^{+\infty} z^{-(n-1)/\alpha} |\cos z|\, dz
$$
that diverges to $+\infty$ if $(n-1)/\alpha < 1$, i.e. if $\alpha > n-1$.

Answer (score 1):

For $n=1$, every function in a Sobolev space is a.e. equal to a continuous function (note this is not the same thing as "a.e. continuous").  But $f = 1_{(0,\infty)}$ is bounded and smooth except at 0, but not a.e. equal to any continuous function.  (Any function a.e. equal to $f$ will equal 1 on a dense subset of $(0,\infty)$ and 0 on a dense subset of $(-\infty,0)$, so it cannot be continuous at 0.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a counter example:  $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+|x|^{-\alpha}}$